# ContentFul: Unable to retrieve images in RichText

Tags: javascript, contentful

When I embed an image in rich text, I think I get two responses, sys and fields, but why can't I get them?
The plan is using the free plan.

--ps--
I use a DeepL

```
{
  nodeType: "embedded-asset-block",
  content: [],
  data: {
    target: {
      sys: {
        id: "roh929XgOJMh1YF23UYW2",
        type: "Link",
        linkType: "Asset",
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: How are you requesting the data (Contentful REST CDA or GraphQL)?

Comment: I'm using GraphQL to make the request.

Answer (score 1):

Contentful DevRel here.  To get the linked asset data you have to adjust the query to include it.

For the following RichText Content

[image: Richtext including Contentful logo]

you can retrieve the image information as follows.

```
query {
  quoteCollection(limit: 10) {
    items {
      richText {
        links {
          assets {
            block {
              title
              url
            }
          }
        }
        json
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the example query I'm using the `links` field to access references and assets included in the `richText` field.

[You can read more about RichText queries in the docs](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/graphql/#/reference/schema-generation/rich-text).